# Preload & Cache Images then Delete Older Images from Cache

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app that displays a series of images.

I want to preload the images in the background and put them in the cache.

When a user sees an image, there is no need to continue caching the images since the user cannot go back to it so I want to remove them from the cache.

Can anybody point me to web sites related to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practices in Android Developers site has a solution for a similar situation. You can check it out [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). The only problem is that they use an `LRU` cache that removes the least recently used image and not the most recently used as you want, however you can remove them manually (as a quick fix solution). Hope that helps.